# Rails: referencing independent entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design

I have a Customer model that references a Location model. In the database table, customers table has a foreign key location_id to the locations table.

The relationship is unidirectional. What I mean is,  Location is an independent entity and has no relation with Customer.

What I have is
Customer.rb

```
:belongs_to :location
```

and nothing in Location.rb.

What are the right associations to use for Customer and Location? How should I build the objects in new method?

The error I am getting now is --
Location(#70161843915060) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70161815174700)

### UPDATE - 1

My form is for @customer and uses

```
f.fields_for :location
```

Parameters go as --
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Kz0iGeAA/pxWvZy3vORKshSdQSBndwlWiHiih8lKYqHsggL/sTBPlaukpVanyckdProZyI3zik2N07udpySvMA==", "customer"=>{"name"=>"MNC", "location"=>{"name"=>"HY"}

Answer (score 1):

in your Customer.rb

```
belongs_to :location
```

in your location.rb

```
has_many :customers
```

its just example

```
location = Location.first
@customer = location.customers.new
```

Comment: Still have the same error. My form is for @customer and uses `f.fields_for :location`. Parameters go as 

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Kz0iGeAA/pxWvZy3vORKshSdQSBndwlWiHiih8lKYqHsggL/sTBPlaukpVanyckdProZyI3zik2N07udpySvMA==", "customer"=>{"name"=>"MNC", "location"=>{"name"=>"HK"}

Comment: you need to pass location_id in hidden field.. or you can show the dropdown to user which collect all location and user can select location from that dropdown.

Comment: I am trying to create customer and location in one save. Currenty location is a combo box that allows for select an existing location as well as input a new location. The users are sales people who dont want to operate more than one screen.

Comment: it should be like <%= f.select :location,options_for_select(@locations.collect{|c| [c.name , c.id]}),{:include_blank => "Select Location"},class: 'form-control custom-form-control'  %> in which @locations = Location.all  and select box contain the value as id and name as location name

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. customer.rb

    belongs_to :location,foreign_key: :location_id

 2. location.rb

    has_many :customers

add this code in your controller 


    when creating a new location for a customer:

     @location = Location.new(params[:location])
     @location.customers.create(params[:customers])
```